# How to handle checkbox click event in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a boolean field like a flag to state that row is deleted or not in the table. It displayed using checkbox, so if the data has been deleted, the checkbox value is true and vice versa.

Below is the code to display the table:

```
<table id="tblEvent" class="display" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PIC)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PIC)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tblEvent").dataTable({
        "order": [[1, "desc"]]
    });
});
```

In the table I can click the checkbox but I don't know how to handle the click event because I'm using datatables to display the data. How to handle checkbox event using datatable?

Comment: `$('#tblEvent input[type="checkbox"]).click(function() { ...`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess you are using a paginated table, and are facing the problem that your click handler not are working when you change pages?

The solution suggested in comments would work on a 1-page dataTable, but is useless if you change pages or the dataTable otherwise is redrawn :

```
$('#tblEvent input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    console.log('suggested-in-comment', 'click');
});
```

...Only works on the first page. You must use a *delegated event* to be sure that the checkboxes always is bound to the click-handler :

```
$('#tblEvent').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    console.log('best', 'click');
});
```

demo with both / proof of concept -> **http://jsfiddle.net/o4mhqpr3/**

Comment: thanks, it also works, I think datatables has a special/built-in function to handle this, but from the answers I've got, it can be done by using jQuery

Comment: @Willy, no - not really. An alternative would be to listen on dataTables `draw.dt` event.  dataTables renders everything from a cached set of rows and columns, this often conflicts with developers desire to add special functionality to DOM-elements.  But glad to hear you got it to work :)

Comment: @Willy, please accept the answer if it helped you out! Marking it as accepted closes the question and indicates to future users having the same problem, that this is a valid solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [datatables with selection capabilities](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) you can use listeners ([select](https://datatables.net/reference/event/select) and [deselect](https://datatables.net/reference/event/deselect) events).

```
table.on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {});
table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code or information from your links in your answer since links are prone to breaking